# cannot instantiate service object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do some refactoring for my Rails application.

I have created a QuizCompletion service object (app/services/quiz_completion.rb):

```
class QuizCompletion
  def initialize(quiz, user)
    @quiz = quiz
    @user = user
  end

  def pass?
    wrong_answers = 0
    @quiz.questions.each do |question|
      answer = @user.answers.where("question_id = ?", question.id).first
      if !answer.correct
        wrong_answers += 1
      end
    end
    if wrong_answers > 2
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my QuestionsController I try to instantiate the Service Object:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user
  def show
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    @question = Question.next(params[:id])
    if @question != nil
      redirect_to quiz_path(@quiz.id, question_id: @question.id)
    else
      evaluation = QuizCompletion.new(@quiz, current_user)  #instantiate Service Object!
      if evaluation.pass? 
        Quiz.complete(current_user, @quiz)
        redirect_to quiz_complete_path(@quiz.id)
      else
        redirect_to quiz_fail_path(@quiz.id)
      end
    end
  end
```

private
end

However, when I run the controller test, I'm getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: get :show, quiz_id: @quiz.id, id: question3.id
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Quiz:0x007fd781515300>
```

Does someone has an idea what's going on? Why can't I instantiate a QuizCompletion object in my QuestionsController?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Can you also post the code of your test and controller? Where does `@quiz` come from?

Comment: @TheDude, the error occurs on the line where I instantiate the service object: evaluation = QuizCompletion.new(@quiz, current_user)

Comment: @Blue Smith, I add the code of my QuestionsController and put a comment where I instantiate the Service Object. quiz is a instance variable that is set in the questions#show action method.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, apparently the problem was with the naming of my service object. The rails framework got confused about the quiz_completion.rb name because there already exist a Quiz (quiz.rb) model.

So I changed the name of my service object to Evaluation (evaluation.rb):

```
class Evaluation
  def initialize(quiz, user)
    @quiz = quiz
    @user = user
  end

  def pass?
    wrong_answers = 0
    @quiz.questions.each do |question|
      answer = @user.answers.where("question_id = ?", question.id).first
      if !answer.correct
        wrong_answers += 1
      end
    end
    if wrong_answers > 2
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

this name also makes more sense when I call it from the QuestionsController:

```
evaluation = Evaluation.new(@quiz, current_user)
  if evaluation.pass? 
    Quiz.complete(current_user, @quiz)
    redirect_to quiz_complete_path(@quiz.id)
  else
    redirect_to quiz_fail_path(@quiz.id)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I also could not instantiate my first service object- I got this error

```
uninitialized constant MyServiceObject (NameError)
```

I was using spring and had to stop it with: `spring stop` . After that it worked.